# How can I authorize (auth login) a user after registering in Jetstream?

Tags: vuejs3, laravel-9, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

Laravel 9, Jetstream, Inertia, Vue3.

After registering, my user is not authenticated. The system successfully registers (creates a user), but does not log him in. How can I authenticate a user automatically after registering in Jetstream? I have a Jetstream component CreateNewUser, but I don't know what to write and where to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to CreateNewUser class

```
$auth = Auth::attempt([
    'email' => $input['email'],
    'password' => $input['password']
]);

if ($auth) {
    session()->regenerate();
}
```